# Downloads folder is "in process"

Tags: macos, folders

Since about 2 weeks the downloads folder always has the loading line under it, even though there's nothing to download. Do you know what that could mean? There's no antivirus installed on the machine.

> OS X Version 10.9.5

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of things happen when you try to download something from chrome, and close it before finish downloading. If it so, you can try the following steps.

- Went to Chrome -> Downloads and clicked Clear all
- Restart Chrome
- Removed the Download folder from the dock (by dragging it from dock to desktop) and dropped it back on there from your Macintosh
- Check your app store, Is there any pending download available or not. If so take care of it.
- Restart you machine.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks! did not even have to restart the machine.

Comment: Welcome...Even better. :)